# JdbcTokenStore missing flush interval

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

I see that the InMemoryTokenStore has a flush interval to specify how many tokens can be active prior to expired tokens being flushed.  I see no such setting on the JdbcTokenStore.  Is there a way to set this for the JdbcTokenStore?